# Como poder llamar datos de un arreglo en C#

Tags: c#

Buen día espero me puedan orientar, he creado una clase llamada Almacén con los atributos ClaveDeProducto,NombreDelProducto,PrecioUnitario,PrecioVenta,UnidadMedida.
Desde el método principal Main por medio de un arreglo le digo al usuario que mi ingrese los datos y que se muestre los datos en pantalla hasta ahí todo bien.
En este punto estoy atorado.
Quiero realizar una compra solo ingresando la clave del producto, digamos si ingreso la clave 1.
Asigno dos variables mas uno cantidad y el otro total, la cantidad multiplicar con el precio de venta  almacenando en la clave 1  y el tal y mostrar en pantalla.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        
        Almacén[] A = new Almacén[3];
       

        Console.WriteLine("********Ingrese los datos********");
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {

            Console.Write("Ingrese el nombre del producto "+ i +": ");
            string nombreProducto = (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Ingrese el precio unitario "+ i + ": ");
            double precioUnitario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Ingrese el precio de venta "+ i + ": ");
            double precioVenta = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Ingrese la unidad de medida " + i + ": ");
            string unidadMedida = (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("\n");

            A [i] = new Almacén(claveProducto,nombreProducto,precioUnitario,precioVenta,unidadMedida);
        }

       Console.WriteLine("********Productos almacenados********");
        Console.WriteLine("Clave del producto: {0}",0);
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre del producto: {0}", A[0].nombreProducto);
        Console.WriteLine("Precio unitario: ${0:N1}", A[0].precioUnitario);
        Console.WriteLine("Precio de venta: ${0:N1}", A[0].precioVenta);
        Console.WriteLine("Unidad de medida: {0}", A[0].unidadMedida);
        Console.Write("\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Clave del producto: {0}", 1);
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre del producto: {0}", A[1].nombreProducto);
        Console.WriteLine("Precio unitario: ${0:N1}", A[1].precioUnitario);
        Console.WriteLine("Precio de venta: ${0:N1}", A[1].precioVenta);
        Console.WriteLine("Unidad de medida: {0}", A[1].unidadMedida);
        Console.Write("\n");
        

    }


}
```

Esta es mi clase Almacén

```
class Almacén
{
  
   private int ClaveDeProducto;
   private string NombreDelProducto,UnidadMedida;
   private double PrecioUnitario,PrecioVenta;
   

    public int claveProducto
    {
        get { return ClaveDeProducto; }
        set { ClaveDeProducto = value; }
    }
    
    public string nombreProducto
    {
        get { return NombreDelProducto; }
        set { NombreDelProducto = value; }
    }

    public double precioUnitario
    {
        get { return PrecioUnitario; }
        set { PrecioUnitario = value; }
    }
    public double precioVenta
    {
        get { return PrecioVenta; }
        set { PrecioVenta = value; }
    }
    public string unidadMedida
    {
        get { return UnidadMedida; }
        set { UnidadMedida = value; }
    }


    public Almacén()
    {
        ClaveDeProducto = 0;
        NombreDelProducto = "";
        PrecioUnitario = 0.0;
        precioVenta = 0.0;
        UnidadMedida = "";
    }

    public Almacén(int ClaveDeProducto, string NombreDelProducto, double PrecioUnitario, 
        double PrecioVenta, string UnidadMedida )
    {
        this.ClaveDeProducto = ClaveDeProducto;
        this.NombreDelProducto = NombreDelProducto;
        this.PrecioUnitario = PrecioUnitario;
        this.PrecioVenta = PrecioVenta;
        this.UnidadMedida = UnidadMedida;

    } 
    
  }
```

Hasta el momento me muestra es to en pantalla

Solo me falta un método o función que para realizar la compra con solo ingresar la clave del producto, si el usuario ingresa la clave de producto 1, y quiere un cantidad de 2 piezas o kilos ahí hacer el calculo de precio de ventas con cantidad y mostrar el total.

Comment: Amigo TheOlirgarch, lo quiero lograr es esto una vez ya mostrado en pantalla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener el producto según el Id es muy sencillo, puedes utilizar linq, también puedes mejorar tú código de la siguiente manera:

```
    Almacen[] almacen = new Almacen[3];

    Console.WriteLine("********Ingrese los datos********");
    for (var i = 0; i < almacen.Length; i++)
    {
        var numero = i + 1;
        Console.Write("Ingrese el nombre del producto "+ numero +": ");
        var nombreProducto = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Ingrese el precio unitario "+ numero + ": ");
        var precioUnitario = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Ingrese el precio de venta "+ numero + ": ");
        var precioVenta = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Ingrese la unidad de medida " + numero + ": ");
        var unidadMedida = (Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("\n");

        almacen [i] = new Almacen(i,nombreProducto,precioUnitario,precioVenta,unidadMedida);
    }


    foreach (var producto in almacen)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("********Productos almacenados********");
        Console.WriteLine("Clave del producto: {0}",producto.ClaveProducto);
        Console.WriteLine("Nombre del producto: {0}", producto.NombreProducto);
        Console.WriteLine("Precio unitario: ${0:N1}", producto.PrecioUnitario);
        Console.WriteLine("Precio de venta: ${0:N1}", producto.PrecioVenta);
        Console.WriteLine("Unidad de medida: {0}", producto.UnidadMedida);
        Console.Write("\n");
    }


    Console.WriteLine("********Realizar Compra********");
    Console.WriteLine("Deseas realizar una compra: s/n");
    var valor = Console.ReadLine();
    var flag = valor.Equals("s");
    while (flag)
    {
        Console.Write("Ingrese la clave del producto: ");
        var claveProducto = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad: ");
        var cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var productoCompra = almacen.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ClaveProducto == claveProducto);
        if (productoCompra == null) Console.Write("El producto ingresado no existe");
        var total = productoCompra.PrecioVenta * cantidad;
        Console.WriteLine($"Total a pagar: {total}");
        Console.WriteLine("Deseas realizar otra compra: s/n");
        valor = Console.ReadLine();
        flag = valor.Equals("s");
    }
```

Comment: Ok amigo deja verifico eso

Comment: Excelente, me avisas si te funciona.

Comment: Me marco error amigo

Comment: Ya edite de nuevo  el código amigo

Comment: Que error te marca ?

Comment: Una excepción de que falta una variable, pero ya actualice de nuevo el código para que lo verifiques y subí una imagen de que me muestra en pantalla.

Comment: Ok amigo verificare el código y te aviso.

Comment: Gracias amigo TheOligarch funciono bien con la modificación que le realizaste.